# the name "CondidatType"contains illegal characters

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have error when I overdding formType fosuserBundle,I create entity then I generate form but I have this error now when I change name of form fos_user in config.yml .. name attributs in formtype doesn't content illegal characters:

[image]

Code FormType:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

    /**
     *Class DefaultController.
     */
    class CondidatType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * function buildForm when I add many attributs added by entity User.
         *
         * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array                                        $options
         */
        public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                    ->add('civilite', null, array('label' => 'Civilité'))
                    ->add('nom', null, array('label' => 'Nom'))
                    ->add('prenom', null, array('label' => 'Prénom'))
                    ->add('pays', null, array('label' => 'Pays'))
                    ->add('telephone', null, array('label' => 'Téléphone'))
                    ;
        }

        /**
         * function get Parent Form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
        }

        /**
         * name for this form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'condidat_user_registration';
        }

        /**
         * name for this form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->getBlockPrefix();
        }

        /**
         * function setDefaultOptions.
         *
         *@param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
         */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle/Entity/User',
            ));
        }
    }
```

code service.yml:

```
services:
  condidat_user_registration:
      class: AppBundle\Form\CondidatType
      public: true 
      tags:
          - { name: form.type, alias: condidat_user_registration }
```

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
  from_email:
      address: "testapp@testapp.com"
      sender_name: "Test App"
  registration:
      form:
          name: AppBundle\Form\CondidatType
      confirmation:
          enabled: true
```

now how to resolve this error

Comment: `'data_class' => 'AppBundle/Entity/User'` => `'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `setDefaultOptions()` method.

`AppBundle/Entity/User` - this is a path to file.

`AppBundle\Entity\User` - this is a FQCN (fully qualified class name;

In namespaces we use FQCN.

So:

```
    /**
     * function setDefaultOptions.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
         ));
     }
```

And substitute name with type in the declaration of your form in config.yml

```
registration:
      form:
          type: AppBundle\Form\CondidatType
```

Comment: @devit2017. I've edited my answer. Also, please - change the header of your question. It is very specific. Maybe try this: "Error when overwriting FOSUser registration form"

Comment: now when i try with type: ... i have this error : Neither the property "civilite" nor one of the methods "getCivilite()", "civilite()", "isCivilite()", "hasCivilite()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\User".

Comment: guess you didn't make this methods for property "civilite". First of all try to make it not mapped ->add('civilite', null, array('label' => 'Civilité', 'mapped' => false )) Then try to add getCivilite and setCivilite methods to your user "Condidat" entity